# Class method expectation not working

Tags: ocmock

I tried to use class method stubs and expectations with new OCMock 3.0 syntax but I did not succeed. :(

I would like to verify that a class method is called. In order to understand why my expectation is not fulfilled, I simplified the example to this:

```
- (void)test_should_call_XXX {
    id classMock = OCMClassMock([NSString class]);

    [NSString string];

    OCMVerify([classMock string]);
}
```

I do not understand why this lines of code do not work:

```
OCMockObject(NSString): Method string was not invoked
```

I tried `OCMVerify(ClassMethod([classMock string]));`with the same result.

Regards,

Quentin

Answer (score 1):

Class methods on `NSString` cannot be verified. Please have a look at the limitations section 10.5 in the documentation: http://ocmock.org/reference/#limitations

Comment: and ```[NSString string];``` should be  ```[classMock string]```